# Exclude Post ID from Array Specified in Custom Field

Tags: php, array

I have a custom field 'exclude' and the value would be a particular post, let's say 2124. Within the array I want to then call this custom field for the exclude => field but is this even possible?

Comment: What are you excluding this post from? From being displayed on your site? Can you provide us with what you have so far?

Comment: I've got a few pages where a list of posts are pulled in. And it's being excluded solely from that page.

Comment: So on specific page, you want to exclude certain posts from showing? Why not use a category you can check off on posts you want to exclude and an is_page conditional. Then on your loop, you can check what page it is, and if it's that page, exclude posts from that category - assuming you have the same loop on other pages and just want to adjust the loop on this specific page. If that sounds like it'll work for you, I can provide some code as an answer. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Comment: Basically I have a custom page type created and within that page template I have the normal array to get a list of the posts. Within the array I have exclude => '',

Obviously I can't put php the_field ('exclude_field') in the quotation marks to pull in the custom field that specifies the ID of the post(s) I want to exclude with 'exclude_field' being the name of the custom field.

But is there a way to make this work?

Comment: edit your question, add more detail and your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague and you haven't given any example code, but the following may work for you:

```php
<?php

    global $post;

    // Arguments
    $args = array('
        /* Enter your arguments in here... */
    ');

    // The query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        // Exclude ID
        $exclude_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'exclude_field', true );

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() && $post->ID !== $exclude_id ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            /*
                Output here, e.g.
                echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
                echo '<div>' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
            */

        }
    }

?>
```